# We are quite new into Cryptonote technology! We are looking for a web wallet!

Tags: blockchain, cryptonote, light-wallet, web-wallet

https://github.com/mybtcfx/4xbitcoin

This is our coin based on CryptoNote.
We have made our coin and started mining as well. We have also worked onto our block explorer !!

Now ae are looking toward building a web-based wallet for out miners!

is anyone aware of detailed guide about how to build a web-based wallet for cryptonote based coins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same base that [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com) is using. It's a really nice web wallet.

You can take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero).

Comment: We are also looking for more Cryptonote Consultations. I believe you are very knowledgeable in this domain. Would it be convenient for you to guide us a little bit more onto our project? 

Probably we can communicate on a personal level (telegram / Skype) based on your convenience. Any help will be appreciated! please drop a message to me on tejas@undigit.com

We can also discuss on the financials against your consultation.